# Unable to cast generic type implementing Any to Any

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store dynamic objects using `Any`.

My problem is that the `add_bar` function does not work as I expect. I would think that I could add a `Bar<T>` where `T: Any + 'static` to a vector of `Bar<Any>`, but I get a *mismatched types* error.

If I follow the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879372/expected-trait-coreopsfnmut-found-type-parameter), I get a *non-scalar cast* error.

```rust
use std::any::Any;

struct Bar<S: ?Sized> {
    ev: fn(S) -> bool,
}

// test case
struct Foo {
    pub hello: Vec<Bar<Any>>
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn add_bar<T: Any + 'static>(&mut self, baz: Bar<T>) {
        let baz2 = baz as Bar<_>; // non-scalar cast
        self.hello.push(baz2); // without using baz2: mismatched types. expected trait Any, found type parameter
    }
}

fn bla() {
    let mut my_foo = Foo { hello: Vec::new() };
    fn e(v: f64) -> bool {
        true
    }
    let my_bar = Bar::<f64> { ev: e };
    my_foo.add_bar::<f64>(my_bar);
}
```

The only solution so far is to make the `ev` function take an `Any` as its argument, but that doesn't seem very elegant because all possible `ev` functions would have to contain their own downcasting.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Any`?

Comment: This is actually part of a bigger system. Basically, I want a bunch of objects each containing a function that can use some internal state, and the type of the internal state varies.    

After thinking about this a bit, it's obvious that my thinking was too complicated and what I was doing was simply not the Rust way (I'm new to this), but I'd still be interested in why the casting doesn't work.

Comment: Another problem, besides those described in the answers below, is that it is *impossible* to write a function which accepts or returns `Any`. `Any` is a trait, therefore when it is used in a type position, it means a trait object. `fn(Any)` is a function which accepts *bare* trait object. However, bare trait objects are unsized types which can't be passed by value, so it is just impossible to write a function which would have such signature.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev gooi point, editing my answer to answer that and propose an alternative approach

Answer (score 3):

in general you *can* cast a `Foo<T>` to a `Foo<Any>` (or at least a trait object like `&Foo<T>` to `&Foo<Any>`).

I.e. this is legal:

```
struct Foo<T: ?Sized> { b: T }

fn main() {
    let b = Foo { b: 32 };
    let _b2: &Foo<Any> = &b;
}
```

what is *not* legal is this:

```
fn test(a: i32) { println!("{}", a+1); }
let t: fn(i32) = test;
//let t2: fn(Any) = t as fn(Any);
//                  ^~~~ this is the non-scalar cast
```

And it can't be legal because it would not be type-safe, as in general a function that accepts a `i32` would not know what to do with a `Any` (if you called `test` through `t2`, how would it perform the `a+1` in its body?).

That's why, as you say, making `ev` a `fn(Any) -> bool` makes your program compile. If you allow the `fn` to take a `Any`, your are indeed forcing each `ev` to contain its downcasting logic, but that is a feature, not a limitation. By the way (thanks @VladimirMatveev for the comment) it would need to be a `fn(Box<Any>)`, because `Any`is a trait and you can't store a bare trait; you can only store a reference to it and have a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/trait-objects.html).

That said, (while I'm not sure what your real world requirements are) based on your comment...

> Basically, I want a bunch of objects each containing a function that
>   can use some internal state, and the type of the internal state varies

...why do you want to store the function inside the struct? The usual way to add behavior to different types of environments is to impl a trait for them. I know this may not be what you're trying to do, but please bear with me for a bit, I'll add an example at the end that does store the fn in the struct. 
For now, note that (wiht the fn out of the struct) you could do this:

```
// environments are in the structs
struct Bar1 {
    env1: String,
    env2: i32,
}

struct Bar2 {
    env1: char,
}

// behavior is in the trait
trait Ev {
    // here I'm moving self in ev to reflect
    // what the fn does in your example code 
    fn ev(self) -> bool;
}

// each impl can access the environment of its own struct   
impl Ev for Bar1 {
    fn ev(self) -> bool { (self.env2 == 42) }
}

impl Ev for Bar2 {
    fn ev(self) -> bool { (self.env1 == 'a') }
}

struct Foo {
    // Now we have a Vec of Ev trait objects instead of Any
    // Ev is a bare trait so we box it
    pub hello: Vec<Box<Ev>>,
}

impl Foo {
    // a T: Ev is any of Bar1, Bar2...
    pub fn add_bar<T: Ev + 'static>(&mut self, baz: T) {
        let baz2: Box<Ev> = Box::new(baz);
        self.hello.push(baz2); 
    }
}

// example of use
fn main() {
    let mut my_foo = Foo { hello: Vec::new() };

    let my_bar = Bar2 { env1: 'a' };
    my_foo.add_bar(my_bar);
}
```

I'm not sure if this can be applied in your real-world scenario. The most notable functional difference even with your example code is that in your case the *client* of your code can decide what behavior to attach to a specific struct, while with the trait approach you have to decide on one impl for the trait when you create a new `Bar`.

However, building on the trait approach, if you do need to have the fn inside the struct, you can now do it without it being generic. I.e you can have

```
struct Bar {
    env1: u8,
    // ev is not generit, it explicitly takes a Bar
    ev: fn(a: &Bar) -> bool
}

// the trait defers to the fn stored in the struct
impl Ev for Bar {
    fn ev(&self) -> bool { (self.ev)(&self) }
}
```

[full example on the playground](http://is.gd/Ve7CBu)

Answer (score 1):

When you write `let my_bar = Bar::<f64> { ev: e };` you have

```
my_bar.ev: fn(f64) -> bool
```

You want to cast this to a `Bar<Any>`, but `Bar<Any>` has

```
my_bar.ev: fn(Any) -> bool
```

Obviously you can't do this, since a `fn(f64) -> bool` can't accept, say, a `Vec<i32>`, yet `Vec<i32>` is an `Any` type! The behaviour doesn't make sense! (Strictly speaking, it primarily doesn't make sense because `Any` isn't a type, but a trait.)

Perhaps you want to have some type `BarAny` for which you can write

```
my_bar_any.downcast_ref::<f64>(): Option<&Bar<f64>>
```

That's sensible, but the `Any` must be on another level - where `BarAny` is. In fact, `BarAny` is just a restricted form of `Any`:

```
struct Foo {
    pub hello: Vec<Box<Any>>
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn add_bar<T: 'static>(&mut self, baz: Bar<T>) {
        self.hello.push(Box::new(baz));
    }
}
```

Note that the box is needed because `Any` is not sized.